# How to compare a string with an Enum in a switch?

Tags: java, switch-statement

i have an enum like below:

```
public enum TripType {
  TRIP1,
  TRIP2,
  TRIP3,
  TRIP4
}
```

Then i have a method which receives a string parameter `setupTravel(String tripType)` and i need to check the value of `tripType` with a `TripType`. I wish to use a switch-case as below:

```
setupTravel(String tripType){
    switch (tripType){
      case TripType.TRIP1.toString():
        setup1();
        break;
      case TripType.TRIP2.toString():
        setup2();
        break;
    }
}
```

But, in the line `TripType.TRIP1.toString()` it complains with:
`Constant expression required`

How can i fix it?

Comment: Is setupTravel your method?  Does it have to take a string?

Comment: Just a hint. Not sure if it will be useful for you. You can use an enum constructor to do different things on each enum value. You can avoid a switch case or if-else ladder completely. I always find that more readable and better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
setupTravel(String tripType) {
  try {
    switch (TripType.valueOf(tripType)) {
      case TRIP1:
        setup1();
        break;
      case TRIP2:
        setup2();
        break;
    }
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    // Handle invalid trip type here
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be good to point out that this throws an exception if `tripType` doesn't contain something that is not part of the enumeration (e.g. `TRIP5`).

Comment: Catch an IllegalArgumentException for wrong strings.. And 
`TripType.` is should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Since your method seems to switch on the Enum string,  why not just use the Enum?  You may want to include a `default` unless you have all Enums in the switch block.

```
setupTravel(TripType type){
    switch (type){
      case TRIP1:
        setup1();
        break;
      case TRIP2:
        setup2();
        break;
    }
}
```

You would call it as

```
setupTravel(TripType.TRIP1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it will be useful for you, You can use an enum constructor instead of using a switch case.
Something like this:

```
public enum TripType {
    TRIP1("setup1"), TRIP2("setup2");
    String setup;
    private TripType(String setup) {
        this.setup = setup;
    }
    public String getSetup() {
        return setup;
    }
    public static TripType getTripTypeByName(String name) {
        return Arrays.stream(TripType.values()).filter(t -> t.name().equalsIgnoreCase(name)).findAny().orElse(null);
    }
}
```

And getting enum based on the name, you can use like this:

```
TripType tripType = TripType.getTripTypeByName("trip1");
System.out.println(tripType != null ? tripType.getSetup() : null);
```